# .Net MVC 6 Authorization from desktop app

Tags: .net, cookies, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

Using the boilerplate code form the project template I created a .net core mvc6 webapp with login.

The Login controller is:

```
 // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
```

The LoginViewModel is:

```
 public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

I can log in from the login webpage.

I want to use controllers (as API) with [Authorization] attribute in this project from a desktop .net c# program. For this I am planing to get a cookie from the login controller and access the API with the cookie.

The code for the desktop software to get a cookie is (copy paste form StackOverflow with added JSON serialization):

```
      private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create(loginUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        http.KeepAlive = true;
        http.Method = "POST";
        http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var login = new LoginViewModel();
        login.Email = txtUserName.Text;
        login.Password = txtPassword.Text;
        var postData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(login);

        byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;

        using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

//IT STOPS HERE WITH HTTP 400

```
        // Probably want to inspect the http.Headers here first
        http = WebRequest.Create(authorized) as HttpWebRequest;
        http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

The LoginViewModel class has the same properties as in the webapp.

Unfortunately it does not work, the HTTP Response is 400.

Questions:

1. Is my logic OK? If yes, could you point out where is the code wrong?
2. Is cookie based authentication OK to access a Restful web api?
3. Can it be used for a webservice with low trafic volume, given that it will be HTTPS?
4. Is there any better way to do it without any 3rd party providers like strompath or auth0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my logic OK? If yes, could you point out where is the code wrong?

If your API expects data as JSON, then you probably will have to set the `ContentType` header appropriately:

```cs
http.ContentType = "application/json";
```

(If you are still getting `400` as status code, check the response for any hint from the API on what you are sending wrong).

> Is cookie based authentication OK to access a Restful web api?

It is possible, but probably not the best way to do it, specially from non-browser clients. 
A popular choice nowadays to access secured APIs is through Bearer Tokens. You obtain the token from an identity provider endpoint (either your app or a third party provider such as Auth0 or StormPath), and you include that token in the `Authorization` header on every request to the API. See https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/ for some discussions on this.

Your API would have to be prepared to accept bearer tokens as an alternative way of authorizing access. In the case of .Net Core, some middleware would inspect the incoming token in the HTTP header, validate it, and set the ClaimsPrincipal so that you `Authorize` attribute keeps working as expected.

Usually tokens are [JWTs (Json Web Tokens)](https://jwt.io/introduction/) that can be inspected and debugged (they are signed, not encrypted), which is a better experience that using cookies. You can, for example, look at the token to see if it is expired and get a new one, avoiding errors from the API.

> Can it be used for a webservice with low trafic volume, given that it will be HTTPS?

It can but, again, this would only be done if you don't have control over your API to add support for tokens.

> Is there any better way to do it without any 3rd party providers like strompath or auth0?

The JWT format is open and standard. You could potentially generate your owns and return them from an authentication API that you would need to build (that would return the tokens instead of the session cookie).

Once you have the JWTs, Microsoft offers a package that will help you protect your API with JWT tokens:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Jwt
```

Authentication, however, is easy to get wrong. This is where 3rd party providers like Stormpath or Auth0 will come really handy. Disclaimer: I work for Auth0.